# flask server works when sent request directly but returns 404 when request recevied through redirect from another flask application

Tags: python, url, redirect, flask, http-status-code-404

I implemented a microservice style application using Flask. The application consists of three flask apps each running at the same ip address but different port number. The application is hosted on an EC2 instance and locally as well. The problem I will outline occurs on both deployment options.

One flask application serves as a api gateway. A client makes a request to this application and the app will reroute to one of the other two flask apps (users or advertisements application).

When I make a direct request to the two non-api gateway apps, the request is processed correctly. BUT, when i make a request to the api gateway, the request is routed to the correct app, then that app outputs that it is redirecting to the correct route but then returns a 404 page not found.

This problem occurs with POST and PUT requests but GET requests seem to be working fine.

Here is the code for the gateway:

```
@api_gateway.route('/users', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
@cross_origin()
def users_router():
    return redirect(http://localhost:5000, 307)


@api_gateway.route('/advertisements', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@cross_origin()
def advertisements_router():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(http://localhost:3000 + "?" +
                        request.query_string.decode('ascii'), code=307)
    return redirect(http://localhost:3000, code=307)
```

Here is the code for the user app:

```
@user_microservice.route('/', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
@cross_origin()
def user_handler():
    printRequest(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(url_for('.user_register'))
        return redirect(url_for('.user_register'), 307)
    else:
        print(url_for('.user_login'))
        return redirect(url_for('.user_login'), 307)


@user_microservice.route('/user_register', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def user_register():
    init_db()
    user = create_user(request)
    db_session.add(user)
    try:
        db_session.commit()
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
        raise HTTP_CODES["Conflict"]
    return jsonify(response="User entered into database"), HTTP_CODES["OK"]


@user_microservice.route('/user_login', methods=['PUT'])
@cross_origin()
def user_login():
    login_credential_email = request.json['email_address']
    login_credential_password = request.json['password']
    user = User.query.filter(User.email_address == login_credential_email).first()
    print(user)
    if user and user.verify_password(login_credential_password):
        identity = {
            "email_address": user.email_address,
            "store_name": user.store_name,
            "store_address": user.store_address,
            "city": user.city
        }
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=identity)
        return jsonify(access_token=access_token, logged_in_as=f"welcome {login_credential_email}"), HTTP_CODES["OK"]
    else:
        raise HTTP_CODES["Unauthorized"]
```

UPDATE: The routing is working properly when I run in Windows but does not work when I'm using linux. I hope this might allude to what could be the issue.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without a [mcve]

Comment: sorry about that, i pressed enter and submitted the question without putting the code. my bad